# Clipping/ "random" teleporting in Godot 4 on map imported from Blender

Tags: blender, godot

I've created a map in Blender and imported it in Godot 4. Somehow, when walking up the edges on the outer part of it, the character gets teleported, even one time fell through the map. Does someone know why this could be?

Here is the map:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLgwV.jpg

Here is a gif showing this issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G07M.jpg

Here is the blend file if someone wants to test this:
https://anonfiles.com/19wdO7k9zc/Environment_blend

I've tried this on a minimal example, i.e. importing the blend file and creating a CharacterBody3D with template script, it still happens.

I've tried not using the automatic collision shape creation on import of the .blend file (by not adding '-col' at the end of the scene collection in blender) and instead manually generated a trimesh static body within Godot, but it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue (at least I think. Your links aren't all up still, so it's hard to confirm). Drove myself crazy looking for a solution.

In my case, I ended up having multiple vertices at the same location in my .blend file. For some reason Merge Vertices wasn't doing anything (I'm a Blender noob though so idk), but manually selecting one of the overlapping vertices and dissolving it did the trick for me.

Hope this helps you and / or anyone else with this issue.